# Easy way to keep a list of SharePoint links within SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have around 300 Reporting Services reports in SharePoint 2013, total, in ten different folders (by department), but my sales team's folder has around 100 of those and they find it difficult to remember which ones they care about and quickly navigate to them. Is there a way they can easily set up a list or some sort of page within SharePoint that points to the reports they care about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tag/index your documents and then create a list and a view to that list that show documents that are indexed with a certain tag. For example shows only documents that contains the tag "important"

Answer (score 1):

Create a Document library and add Document link content type. In this way you can manage the links on different views.

Answer (score 0):

You can use metadata while making any entry in a list. So when you are creating any list make a use of that metadata and show only those list items which contains that tag.

Please correct me if i understand your question wrong

Thanks